# Java Schedule activities with Joda Time like Timer

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, jodatime

I am searching a way to do a scheduled activity every tot time. For example, at hh:00:00 i want the java execute the command

```
System.out.println("It's " + hh + " o'clock");
```

I have done something similar time ago with the Java classes Timer and Calendar, now that I have met the Joda Time  library I wanted to know if there is something similar to Timer class in Joda Time.

Comment: maybe spring scheduler ?

Comment: There is a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class in the JDK. It may be sufficient for your requirements. For a more CRON-like approach, take a look at the [Quartz scheduler framework](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: There's also Quartz scheduler.

Comment: @Henrik - yeah, but would be great if we had the answer to this before we get into scheduling with a combination of Joda and Quartz - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319458/any-relation-between-quartz-api-and-joda-time-api

Comment: With such scheduler it would be easy to test scheduled tasks.
JodaTIme has method to change global time.

Answer (score 0):

The questions seems to confuse scheduling of the task with the purpose of representing underlying DateTimes. As mentioned, Quartz would be a suitable solution for the scheduling piece.

To try answer you question as best I can, from the JodaTime perspective, there isn't a Timer implementation in the API docs that I can see. I tend to think of JodaTime as the human representation of the underlying machine timeline, i.e. what's on the system time in a readable format.

For what you're looking to do in the print you can do:

`System.out.println("It's " + new DateTime().hourOfDay() + " o'clock");;`

If you're looking for a bit more on clocks/timers in JodaTime the nearest thing I can find that might help you is there is  a `DateTimeUtils.getMillis()` which uses the underlying System implementation, note you can change this for a different Timer/Clock of your choosing.

```
    /**
     * System millis provider.
     */
    static class SystemMillisProvider implements MillisProvider {
        /**
         * Gets the current time.
         * @return the current time in millis
         */
        public long getMillis() {
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## ScheduledExecutorService

See the Executor classes built into Java 5 and later. Specifically the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Search StackOverflow for many Questions and Answers with more info.