# Any relation between Quartz API and Joda Time API?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jodatime

Is it possible to create a date in JodaTime and then make Quartz schedule the job using the JodaTime object? Can we give a Period jodaPeriod to Quartz API in order to run a task for a particular period in a day?

Are the two APIs related and/or compatible in any way?

Comment: Do you want to schedule a job to repeat at an interval specified by a Joda Time period?

Comment: @darrenmc - not just that one use case. I want to be able to do everything that quartz can do, but preferably using joda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AxonFramework has a [QuartzEventScheduler](http://www.axonframework.org/apidocs/2.0/org/axonframework/eventhandling/scheduling/quartz/QuartzEventScheduler.html) which looks like it does what you want.

Here's the [downlaod page](http://www.axonframework.org/download/) and it's under the Apache 2.0 license.

Comment: CQRS (Axon is a CQRS framework) is Command Query Responsibility Segregation - http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: Edd- can you give me some more examples like these ? Looks like this framework uses only a small part of Quartz and joda. There seems to be no support for performing a task repeatedly after a certain Joda Period or Duration. I was looking for more integration between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Quartz provides a pretty comprehensive API that you could extend anyway you wanted.
The hook you would need to create would be against the [Trigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/Trigger.html) interface, I've created one before but not using Joda time.

From the sounds of your question if you want to create a job that runs for a particular period of the day you could also just try using the `CronTrigger`. For example to run every minute between 9am and 11am you could do

```
* 9-10 * * *
```

Obviously Joda makes it much easier to configure but your sysadmins respect you more for cron...

Answer (score 2):

I've started to use Joda Time in newer parts of my company's app and I've found it easier to link to the legacy parts (including Quartz scheduling) by converting the Joda Time object back to java.util.Date which the older parts are still expecting. I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but that is manual. But, I want to avoid date because most of it is deprecated and its likely that Joda will replace the current time system.

Comment: JSR-310 (threeten) https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten will augment Date rather than Joda in Java 8. They have similarities, but there are also many improvements in threeten over Joda.

Answer (score 2):

[TriggerBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html) has a snippet of how to schedule a job by hand:

```
JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class)
         .withIdentity("myJob")
         .build();

Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
         .withIdentity(triggerKey("myTrigger", "myTriggerGroup"))
         .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
             .withIntervalInHours(1)
             .repeatForever())
         .startAt(futureDate(10, MINUTES))
         .build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

You will have to do some conversion work for the startAt() and the withIntervalInHours()...you get the drift

Comment: +1 for the example. I wish that Quart adds some in built joda support. Otherwise I will have to do all conversion and field extraction manually.